# What's this emberjs shorthand called '->'?

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript

I'm reviewing some examples on stackoverflow and I'm noticing a lot of people using -> as in:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'respondents', path: '/'
```

What is this shorthand called and where can I read more about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's CoffeeScript, not actually related to ember.

> CoffeeScript is a little language that compiles into JavaScript. Underneath that awkward Java-esque patina, JavaScript has always had a gorgeous heart. CoffeeScript is an attempt to expose the good parts of JavaScript in a simple way.
>
> The golden rule of CoffeeScript is: "It's just JavaScript". The code compiles one-to-one into the equivalent JS, and there is no interpretation at runtime. You can use any existing JavaScript library seamlessly from CoffeeScript (and vice-versa). The compiled output is readable and pretty-printed, will work in every JavaScript runtime, and tends to run as fast or faster than the equivalent handwritten JavaScript.

http://coffeescript.org/

Comment: Thanks. Will close once time is up.

Comment: You don't have to close, it isn't hurting anyone.